# Create a custom format number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to create a custom format number in Excel:

For example:

When I write: 0, I would like to display: 0+000
When I write: 55, I would like to display: 0+055
When I write: 555, I would like to display: 0+555
When I write: 5555, I would like to display: 5+555

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `0+000` in custom format

[image]

Comment: As `TEXT(value,format)` works very similar to the custom formatting, this is equal to `=TEXT(A1,"0+000")` for a value in A1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with custom formats, you need a formula:

If you have the value to "format" in A1:

```
=TEXT(INT(A1/1000),"0+") & TEXT(MOD(A1,1000),"000")
```

... which will work for up to four-digit numbers.

Comment: custom format possible. Tried and Tested.

Comment: Well, =) that was unexpectedly easy. That might be an undocumented feature - meaning: it will break at some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to get to cell format select custom format.
Theres a text box to the right and simply put the prefix in quotes followed by the number format. Ie
"0+"0

Comment: Is not working for 5+555